# Java dashboard performance

Tags: java, performance, jsf, concurrency, dashboard

I have a simple dashboard in my app, it is customizable per user, and it can have a large number of charts and metrics.
At the moment, this dashboard loads every chart on a single thread, so if one of them takes a bit longer to load the user has to wait until it is ready to see everything.

I want to load every chart on a different thread, but I'm wondering if this could generate a performance problem. The app is used by ~ 10000 users.

I'm using JSF, java and postgresql. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own thread pool and allocate thread to chart only when it's available. That way every chart will get separate thread but will not stress the system.